# Как именно реализованы процессы в Erlang?

Tags: erlang, c++

Вопрос несет сугубо академический характер.
Собственно:

> Erlang is designed for massive concurrency. Erlang processes are light-weight (grow and shrink dynamically) with small memory footprint, fast to create and terminate and the scheduling overhead is low.

Какие условия должны соблюдаться для того, что-бы было возможно реализовать подобную модель, какое API используется? В общем - как реализовать такого рода поведение средствами C/C++ или других языков? В первую очередь интересует не код, а теория.

PS: Когда-то гуглил на эту тему, но, к моему большому удивлению, толкового ответа не нашел. Более того - многие писали о том, что реализовать подобную модель средствами С/C++ невозможно, во что мне верится с трудом.

Comment: А разве не треды используются?

Comment: Идея, в целом, состоит в том, что, перед выполнением, необходимые данные копируются локально для каждого треда и, не в последнюю очередь, за счет этого мы имеем такую модель, тем не менее - мне неизвестно какое API для этого используется, да и, откровенно говоря, я с натяжкой понимаю как именно это все реализовано.

Ну и, например, мне вообще неясно каким образом в erlang можно создавать, буквально сотни тысяч процессов? Почему они так быстры в инициализации ну и т.д.

Comment: На самом деле - я нуб в такого рода вопросах, возможно, я не понимаю чего-то настолько элементарного, что об этом не написали даже в гугле, кто знает :)

Comment: Не знаю как в винде, в POSIX-системах можно использовать POSIX threads. Создать теоретически можно сколь угодно нитей. Главное - как управлять их исполнением.

Comment: Если этот вопрос действительно интересует, надо смотреть код интерпретатора.

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Увидел через гугл

     Erlang является кросс-платформенным языком. Технически это реализовано так же, как и в Жабе — программа транслируется в байт-код, исполняемый виртуальной машиной. 

Смею предположить, что подавляющее количество (их многих тысяч) процессов моделируются в рамках нескольких реальных процессов, возможно запускаемых не разных хостах (узлах кластера).

В принципе так же, как в программной модели MIMD машины (там моделируется море функциональных узлов) моделируем кванты времени. В течении кванта интерпретируем несколько команд байт-кода...

(продолжение сле

Comment: Мои познания говорят, что процесс всего один (1 нода - 1 процесс), и есть Loop, в котором трудятся Erlang процессы.

Проверка тривиальна:
2 E-процесса. Один по таймеру пишет в консоль, второй по сигналу уходит в бесконечный цикл.

Comment: ует. Это оно)

одного моделируемого процесса, затем переходим к другому. В том же темпе моделируем потоки данных. Если идет обмен между моделируемыми процессами  в реально разных процессах, то реально пересылаем (думаю субоптимально группируя их) данные (например через сокеты) с отметками моделирумого времени.

И т.д.

Вообще-то интересно, угадал я или нет. Если кто будет код смотреть киньте ответик.

P.S.

Я просто писал когда-то такую штуку (модель железа и ОС в ней).

Comment: Проблема в том, что треды никогда не блокируют друг друга, как именно это реализовать при использовании Loop'a? Ведь все-равно, при такой модели, блокировки, пускай, даже, кратковременные, неизбежны.

Нашел на просторах сети:

>Erlang basically reimplemented all OS features in userland and it's not limited to allocate memory at page boundaries, so it does need much less memory and is also faster. Maybe they also have some special lock-free implementation for mail-boxes. In any way they can fully avoid expensive thread-blocking calls.

Comment: ИМХО(но не точно): Блокируется ещё как... 

A синхронно посылает Б, в процессе обработки Б синхронно посылает А... И зависли... Точнее у вас будут 2 умерших E-процесса на бесконечном ожидании... А Loop будет спокойно крутить дальше

Comment: @timka_s, тут " thread-blocking calls" IMHO ни при чем. Просто один процесс, посылает другому больше данных, чем есть места в очереди обмена и естественно ожидает, пока данные из этой очереди кто-нибудь не заберет. Получатель же в свою очередь (не читает), а проделывает то же самое (много отправляет) и тоже ждет.

Такое можно ухитриться сделать и с обычными процессами и парой пайпов.

Comment: Они не умершие будут, а просто ждущие на `receive`. Мы же не называем «умершим» процесс, ждущий на `select(2)` или `epoll(7)`. И, ЕМНИП, если кто-то третий такому процессу плюнет в мейлбокс, то он проснется. Ну или я не понял идеи.

Comment: @drdaemon, только не на `receive` оба они (это тривиально), а  на `send` (@timka_s именно это и написал).

А вот не умершие, а ждущие - это точно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Будем считать, что речь идет о BEAM, потому что, вообще говоря, [у Erlang была богатая история](http://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/247/erlang_vm_1.pdf).

Начиная с R13 (см. [презентацию Ульфа Вигера](http://ulf.wiger.net/weblog/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/damp09-erlang-multicore.pdf), стр. 19), при условии, что BEAM собрано с поддержкой SMP, создается несколько шедулеров (число определяется [опцией `+S`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#+S), как они соотносятся с логическими процессорами определяется [флагом `+sbt`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#+sbt)), у каждого есть своя очередь процессов. Процесс — всего лишь структура данных, включающая в себя собственную независимую кучу, стек (даже [два, в случае с HiPE](http://reference.kfupm.edu.sa/content/h/i/the_hipe_x86_erlang_compiler__system_des_77875.pdf), см. стр.4) и все положенные процессу регалии (мейлбокс, словарь процесса, тысячи всякого). Собственно, структуру `struct process` можно посмотреть в исходниках BEAM, в файле [`erl_process.h`](https://code.google.com/p/erlang/source/browse/trunk/erts/emulator/beam/erl_process.h?r=146#176).

И, к вопросу многозадачности — шедулер реализует вытесняющую многозадачность, раз в определенное число *редукций* (по сути, операций) переключаясь на другой процесс. Какой-нибудь драйвер, [как честно предупреждает документация](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/driver.html#id81992) — «this means that all operations in the driver must be non-blocking, and that any crash in the driver will bring the whole emulator down» — может завесить поток или вообще уронить всю VM.

Вот, собственно, и все, вроде бы, если не лезть во всякие тонкости и детали (которых я и сам не шибко в курсе, т.к. потроха BEAM, можно сказать, никогда толком и не трогал).

Comment: спасибо @drdaeman, собственно примерно такой ответ я и ожидал, "не особо углубляясь"

Comment: Отлично. По сути я угадал.

Comment: У меня вопрос, как у ПОЛНОГО DUMMY НУБА в этом ВСЁМ НАБОРЕ СЛОЖНЫХ СЛОВ, какие книги нужно прочитать, чтоб знать столько, сколько вы, и какие. PS: Я живу в Узбекистане учусь в лицее на 1ом курсе и сомневаюсь что поступлю в нормальный ВУЗ, а если и поступлю там такому у нас не учат... :(

Comment: Так вот где вы узнали столько всего?

Comment: гугл и усердие знаний придаст тебе, юный подаван

Comment: :) А если серьёзно, знания каких областей применялись при обсуждении этой темы?

Comment: @Rules, раньше это обычно называли "параллельные вычислительные системы".

Comment: Спасибо, @avp

Comment: @Rules, какие именно слова здесь были сложные? Было много слов специфичных, почти сленговых — да. Им (как и кишкам BEAM) ни в одном ВУЗе учить не будут, если только случайно не попадется, как пример. И остаются термины типа «вытесняющей многозадачности», чтобы понять общую суть которых достаточно [посмотреть в словарь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/430853). Но про них вам, если ВУЗ не сельскохозяйственный, а технический, все равно расскажут. Могут не рассказать про какие-то новые вещи, а остановиться на основах (не менявшихся с 70-х), но научат/заставят самостоятельно искать и читать.

Comment: @drdaeman Спасибо за презентацию, с удовольствием прочитал.